# Load Excel sheet issue with C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a problem with reading an Excel document. I have tried for 4 hours now and can't find to fix it. I have the following code for now.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_sheet.Text)) {

            string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" + textBox_path.Text +
                              ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);

            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + textBox_sheet.Text + "$]",
                conn);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
                Console.WriteLine(row[0].ToString());
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[0].ToString())) {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[1].ToString());
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

The problem is when i try to read in the excel sheet. It loads fine on the form but is taking the first value of the excel sheet as the column header name. I don't want this to happen. The excel sheet has the following format.
[image: Excel Sheet format].

Here is an image of the forms application with the problem.

[image: Here is an image of the forms application with the problem]

As you can see it is loading the first row of the excel sheet into the first row on the Datatable.
I don't want that to happen, but I can't figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string to the spreadsheet has been set to view the first row as a header, `HDR=Yes;`. Simply change it to `HDR=No;`.

Comment: You man, just gave me and my friend the best fail laugh ever! Thx for the great help! It works now :)

Comment: @darophi No worries, we've all been there!